# Quadratic equation solver not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, quadratic

I'm trying to create a quadratic equation solver but it doesn't seem to be working when I put in a coefficient greater than 1? The code and error message is below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
print "Welcome to the quadratic equation solver."
print "The general quadratic equation = ax^2 + bx + c.\n"

def POS(a,b):
#This function gives the point at which the quadratic turns
    tp = float((-b)/(a*2))
    return (tp)

#This allows for the user to input the values of the variables
while True:
    s = raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for a: ")
    try:
        a = float(s)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a numeric value."
print ("Well done.\n")

while True:
    s = raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for b: ")
    try:
        b = float(s)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a numeric value."
print ("Well done.\n")

while True:
    s = raw_input ("Please insert a numerical value for c: ")
    try:
        c = float(s)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a numeric value."
print ("Well done.\n")

#This uses the function to give the co-ordinate of the turning point
print POS(a,b), "is the x-value of the turning point"
print ((a)*(POS(a,b)**2))+((b)*POS(a,b))+c, "is they y-value of the turning point. \n"

#This tells whether the quadratic is positive or negative
if a >0:
    print "The quadratic is positive.\n"

if a<0:
    print "The quadratic is negative.\n"

#This determines the root of the quadratic
root1 = (-b +((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
root2 = (-b -((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
print "The quadratic has a root at x =",root1
if root1 != root2:
    print "The quadratic has another root at x =",

#This uses the discriminant to determine the nature of the quadratic
if (b**2)-(4*a*c) == 0:
    print root1

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) > 0:
    print root1 and root2

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) < 0:
    print "The quadratic contains no roots"

for x in range(-1000,1000):
    quadratic = (a*x**2)+(b*x)+c

#Determines the derivitive and second derivitive of the quadratic
print "The derivitive of the quadratic is: ",2*a,"x", "+",b
print "The second derivitive of the quadratic is"

#Create plot
X = arange (-1000,1000,1)
plot(X, quadratic, linewidth=3, label="quadratic")

#Create title and axes label
title ("Graph of the quadratic")
xlabel ("x")
ylabel ("y")

#grid
grid(True)
legend()
show()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Downloads\test.py", line 49, in <module>
    root1 = (-b +((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is inexact. It's possible `(b**2) - (4*a*c)` is negative.

Comment: Would there be a way to get the programme to show no roots then instead of the error message/

Comment: why don't you do the `if (b**2)-(4*a*c) > 0` test before calculating the roots?

Comment: The problem is that `b**2 - 4*a*c` might be resulting in a very small negative number when it should be zero. It doesn't mean the equation has no roots.

Comment: Don't edit the question beyond little edits like typos or small additions. If you must, delete it -- but it's best to let it stay in StackOverflow for ever.

Comment: You could use [`cmath.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#cmath.sqrt) to get a complex root.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your code:

```
#This determines the root of the quadratic
root1 = (-b +((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
root2 = (-b -((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
print "The quadratic has a root at x =",root1
if root1 != root2:
    print "The quadratic has another root at x =",

#This uses the discriminant to determine the nature of the quadratic
if (b**2)-(4*a*c) == 0:
    print root1

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) > 0:
    print root1 and root2

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) < 0:
    print "The quadratic contains no roots"

for x in range(-1000,1000):
    quadratic = (a*x**2)+(b*x)+c
```

Let's replace `(b**2)-(4*a*c)` with `D`:

```
#This determines the root of the quadratic
D = (b**2)-(4*a*c)

root1 = (-b +(D)**0.5) / (2 * a)
root2 = (-b -(D)**0.5) / (2 * a)

print "The quadratic has a root at x =", root1
if root1 != root2:
    print "The quadratic has another root at x =",

#This uses the discriminant to determine the nature of the quadratic
if D == 0:
    print root1

elif D > 0:
    # old code:
    # print root1 and root2
    # new code:
    print root1, root2

elif D < 0:
    print "The quadratic contains no roots"

for x in range(-1000,1000):
    quadratic = (a*x**2)+(b*x)+c
```

Problem in these two lines:

```
root1 = (-b +(D)**0.5) / (2 * a)
root2 = (-b -(D)**0.5) / (2 * a)
```

If `D` is less than 0, this lines will raise `ValueError` you got. As error message said number cannot be raised to a fractional power. So we have to check if `D` is less than 0 or not.

```
#This determines the root of the quadratic
D = (b**2)-(4*a*c)

# new code:
if D >= 0:
    root1 = (-b +(D)**0.5) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b -(D)**0.5) / (2 * a)

    print "The quadratic has a root at x =", root1
    if root1 != root2:
        print "The quadratic has another root at x =", root2


#This uses the discriminant to determine the nature of the quadratic
# We've already printed root1 and root2
# if D == 0:
#     print root1

# elif D > 0:
#     print root1, root2

# D < 0
else:
    print "The quadratic contains no roots"

for x in range(-1000,1000):
    quadratic = (a*x**2)+(b*x)+c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also switch to Python3 so that instead of a `ValueError` your number will be [implicitly cast to a complex number.](https://ideone.com/Fz8SCr)

```
(-2)**.2
(0.9293164906031477+0.6751879523998812j)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#This uses the discriminant to determine the nature of the quadratic
if (b**2)-(4*a*c) == 0:
    print root1

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) > 0:
    print root1 and root2

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) < 0:
    print "The quadratic contains no roots"
```

Perform this check before you process the roots and break if it is a complex root.

```
>>> a=2
>>> b=4
>>> c=1
>>> delta=math.pow(b,2)-4*a*c
>>> math.sqrt(delta) #raises error for -ve integers
3.4641016151377544 
gamma=math.sqrt(delta)
>>>root1=(-b+gamma)/2/a
>>>root2=(-b-gamma)/2/a
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is caused due to the following part:

```
#This determines the root of the quadratic
root1 = (-b +((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
root2 = (-b -((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
print "The quadratic has a root at x =",root1
if root1 != root2:
    print "The quadratic has another root at x =",

#This uses the discriminant to determine the nature of the quadratic
if (b**2)-(4*a*c) == 0:
    print root1

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) > 0:

    print root1 and root2

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) < 0:
    print "The quadratic contains no roots"
```

Any negative number when raised to a fractional power will return a complex number which the computer is not able to calculate.

In `(b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5` there is a possibility that `b**2` is less than `4*a*c`. In such a case there would occur a `ValueError`.

To prevent this: you should structure your code in the following manner-

```
if (b**2)-(4*a*c) == 0:
    print root1

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) > 0:
    root1 = (-b +((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b -((b**2) - (4*a*c))**0.5) / (2 * a)
    print "The quadratic has a root at x =",root1
    if root1 != root2:
       print "The quadratic has another root at x =",
    print root1 and root2

elif (b**2)-(4*a*c) < 0:
    print "The quadratic contains no roots"
```